# Position: fixed menu not working in Android 4+

Tags: css, responsive-design, android-browser

When using Android 4.1 on my Samsung Galaxy S3 and viewing my [website](http://tempworks.byethost7.com/), I'm trying to get the navigation menu on the left to stay where it is but it doesn't. 
Whenever I click on a link from the menu and refresh the page the page, it bounces halfway down the html page and the links fail to work. It works fine on a desktop browser.

Anyone know how to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 11):

Woohoo, figured it out. Very simple actually. Just needed to add a value to `top` and `left` after setting `position: fixed`.

For example: `position:fixed;top:0px;left:0px;`

Comment: Man, you just saved me so much trouble. All the google results for this bug and this is the real solution. Thanks.

Comment: Yep. setting top wasn't enough. Setting top & left did the trick.